# Why does react not load js script into page on mount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a css file and a js file that imported into my react class like so:

```
import React from 'react'
import '../App.css'
import '../motion'

const Landing = () => {
    return (
        <div id="container">
            <div className="center">
                <h1 className="el-st">El Que Sabe Sabe</h1>
                {/* <span className="scroll">Scroll to shuffle</span> */}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Landing
```

The animation only works when I remove the imported js file , re-add it and save the file leading me to believe the file is not being properly read when the component is mounted.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If it works when you remove, re-add and then saving the files, that means that the state isn't updated per animation iteration.

I am not sure if you are using css animation, or js animation. But either or, i'd suggest implementing a simple `useState` statement somewhere. There really isn't enough information provided.

You can define something like:

```
const [animation, setAnimation] = useState(false);
```

And every time you want to play the animation, just call:

```
setAnimation(!animation);
```